# Regular functions on a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, morphism

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, remark 3.1.1., it is said that:

> if $f,g$ are regular functions on a variety $X$, and if $f=g$ on some nonempty open subset $U\subset X$, then $f=g$ everywhere. Indeed, the set of points $f-g=0$ is closed and dense, hence equal to $X$.

I wonder if the following statement is also true: if $X$ is a variety (projective or affine) and $U\subset X$ is open, then $\mathcal{O}(U)=\mathcal{O}(X)$. The mapping $\phi: f\mapsto f|_U$ is a $k$-algebra morphism from $\mathcal{O}(X)$ to $\mathcal{O}(U)$ and, by the remark above, $\phi$ is injective. Is it also surjective? How do I show that?

Comment: In general it is not surjective.

Comment: How do we show the statement in the remark? Why is the set of points $f-g=0$ closed and dense?

Comment: @AlJebr, the idea is to think locally. For each affine open set $V\subset X$ we see $\mathcal{O}(V)$ as a polynomial ring. This way $f\big|_V, g\big|_V$ are polynomials and $V\cap\{f=g\}$ is an algebraic set in $V$, therefore closed in $V$. Now, since all $V$'s cover $X$, we conclude $\{f=g\}$ is closed in $X$ (this is a simple exercise in general topology). Finally, $\{f=g\}$ is dense because it contains a non-empty subset $U$, which is dense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  $U=\mathbb A^1(\mathbb C)\subset X=\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ we have $ \mathcal O(X)=\mathbb C\hookrightarrow \mathcal O(U)=\mathbb C[T]$, which is not surjective.

Comment: would it be different if I considered $K(U), K(X)$ instead of $\mathcal{O}(U)$ and $\mathcal{O}(X)$?

Comment: the reason why I'm asking is because I've seen the following definition of dimension for a variety:  $\dim X:=\text{trdeg}_kK(X)$. If $U\subset X$ is an open subset, we should get $\dim U=\dim X$, but I don't know how to justify that

Comment: @AguirreK Yes, very different: the map $K(X)\to K(U)$ is always (as you correctly suspect) an isomorphism.  In my example we would have $K(X)=K(U)=\mathbb C(T)$.

Answer (score 2):

As @Lord Shark the Unknwon said, this morphism is in general not surjective. For example, take $X$ to be the affine space, and $U=\{ f\neq 0\}$ for some $f\in\mathcal{O}(X)$, $f\neq 0$.
Then $\frac{1}{f}$ is regular on $U$ and has a pole at $U^c$, so it is not the restriction of a regular function over $X$.

Now how about when $codim(U^c)\geq 2$?

Comment: If $\text{codim}(U^c) \geq 2$ it is true if $X$ is normal but I believe they are counter-example in general.